# TypeError: balance.toNumber is not a function

Tags: truffle, ethereum-wallet-dapp, myetherwallet, truffle-migration, truffle-test

I need check that token has no balance when selfDestruct was called, but shows an error that balance.toNumber is not a function in the test file.

**DappTokenSale.sol**

```solidity
function endSale() public {
  //Require Admin (Only Admin can end the Sale)
  require(msg.sender == admin);

  //Transfer remaining dapp tokens to admin
  require(tokenContract.transfer(admin, tokenContract.balanceOf((address(this)))));

  // Destroy contract at the end - transfer remaining token to the admin
  admin.transfer(address(this).balance);
```

**DapptokenSale.js**

(This test code is only for **admin.transfer(address(this).balance);** )

```js
balance = web3.eth.getBalance(tokenSaleInstance.address);
assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), 0);
```

Comment: Debug your code: `console.log(balance)`!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`web3.eth.getBalance`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#getbalance) returns a Promise, with the actual balance in Wei a a string. To get the balance, you can use `Promise.then()` or `async/await`:

```js
web3.eth.getBalance(address)
  .then(balance => {
    // You can use balance here
    console.log(balance);
  })
  .catch(console.error);

// or

const getBalance = async () => {
  const balance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);

  // You can use balance here
  console.log(balance);
}
```

Comment: `web3.eth.getBalance` returns a `Promise` object in web3.js v1.x. In web3.js v0.x, it returns the actual balance. Since we don't know what version this dude is using, I suggested (in a comment) that he prints the returned value, in order to see what it is.